# Get Maximum Values of a column as a function of another column

Tags: r

I have a column with a few dozen grades that have been assigned values Good, Average or Poor. I have a different column with employment rates. I want the maximum employment rate associated with Good, Average and Poor. I can get it to pull the value for each one in three different commands using the code below, but I need it written as a single command similar to this:

`max(unHomework$Employment.Rate[unHomework$Job.Satisfaction.Category == 'Poor'])`

Comment: what about : `tapply(unHomework$Employment.Rate,unHomework$Job.Satisfaction.Category,max)`

Comment: please provide a sample dataset instead of its description

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(unHomework)[, .(MaxER =max(Employment.Rate)), by = Job.Satisfaction.Category]
```